# Invariant Violation: Could not find “store” React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I get the following error using redux in native react

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in
>   the context of "Connect(Lista)". Either wrap the root component in a
>   , or pass a custom React context provider to  and
>   the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Lista) in connect
>   options.

My code is the following

SettingStore

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import Reducers from './Reducer'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

export default SettingStore = () => {
    let store = createStore(Reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))
    return store
}
```

my index  reducer

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import loginreducer from './login.reducer'

export default combineReducers({
    login: loginreducer,

})
```

my index  action

```
import {FETCHING_GETDATA_PARVU} from '../Constante'
import {GetParv} from '../Api/Parvularia.api'



export const getParvuSuccess = (data) => {
    return {type: FETCHING_GETDATA_PARVU, data}
}

export const GetParvu = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {

        dispatch(getData())

        GetParv(1)
        .then(([response, json]) => {
            dispatch(getParvuSuccess(json))
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }
}
```

This is the maintab.reducer of my reducer

```
import {FETCHING_GETDATA_PARVU} from '../Constante'

const initialState =  {
    data: [],
    isFeching: false,
    error: false
}

export default dataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCHING_GETDATA_PARVU:
            return {

                ...state,
                data: action.data,
                isFeching: false
            }        
        default:
        return state
    }
}
```

and let's say this is my app.js of the redux structure

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import Lista from '../screens/Educadora/Lista';
import SettingStore from './SettingStore'

let store = SettingStore()


const Ap = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
     <Lista/>
  </Provider>
)

export default Ap;
```

This last part is the one that generates me more doubt, I think that this is my error but I do not know why I am new in react native

**Edit**

This is where I want to show the query made with redux

```
        import { connect } from 'react-redux'
        import {GetParvu} from '../../Redux/Actions'

       class Lista extends React.Component {
         componentWillMount() {
          this.props.GetParvu()
         render(){
         return(algoaca)
           }
        }
       }
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      parvu: state.data
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      GetParvu: () => {
          return dispatch(GetParvu(1))
      }
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('EqualsMobile', () => Lista);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Lista);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have connecting your component in wrong way. `connect()` is **high order component** that take `mapStateToProps` as an argument to map store to your component.

You can use it in your component like this.

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
   return {state}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(your_component_name);
```

Comment: thanks, but now I was editing my code, I show the component or the screen where I get the error and how I am implementing the above

Comment: do not register app in component, always do it in main index.js file in app root. Remove ```AppRegistry.registerComponent('EqualsMobile', () => Lista);``` this from component and add to index.js file.

Comment: ```import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);```

Comment: I still have the problem u.u
>Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of >"Connect(Lista)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a >custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React >context consumer to Connect(Lista) in connect options.